# elasticsearch document found false

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to access a document with `_id`.

I recently dumped an index from remote server to my local server.

Here's how I am trying to get the document:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/dmap_product_match/dmap_product_match/ZA2JeGsBsz9baORiZSkN
```

And in response:

```
{
    "_index": "dmap_product_match",
    "_type": "dmap_product_match",
    "_id": "ZA2JeGsBsz9baORiZSkN",
    "found": false
}
```

But requesting for the document as a query body returns the document:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/dmap_product_match/_search

{
    "_source": ["s_item_name","r_item_name","human_verdict"],
    "query": {
        "term":{
            "_id": "ZA2JeGsBsz9baORiZSkN"
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: `elasticsearch v7.0.0`.

Comment: what is the `type` and `_id` of the returned document when you search?

Comment: `"_type": "_doc"` and `_id` is as passed; this answers the question.

But since I dumped the whole index, how come the `_type` became `_doc`.

Comment: can you add the result of the working query? Maybe it will show some detail we are missing

Comment: Please can you add what version of Elasticsearch you are using, as this is important

Comment: @RussCam its `7.0.0` and I get it now. They've removed mapping types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ElasticSearch is not finding the document you are asking for because the document type is not well defined in the request.

The api to fetch documents has the following format:

```
GET http://<host>:<port>/<index>/<type>/<docId>
```

According to the request you post, you are looking for the document with the id **ZA2JeGsBsz9baORiZSkN** in the index **dmap_product_match** and type **dmap_product_match**.

Your request should be something like:

```
GET http://localhost:9200/dmap_product_match/_doc/ZA2JeGsBsz9baORiZSkN
```